# SqlServer Internal Error dm_os_enumerate_filesystem -- alloc\storagedmv.cpp

Tags: sql-server, memory-management

I recently started using `sys.dm_os_enumerate_filesystem`.

My SQL Server version is:

> (Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU31) (KB5016884) - 14.0.3456.2 (X64) Sep 2 2022 11:01:50 Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 Standard 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor) )

Everything worked fine until I started querying filesystems where the directories are very large.

The following query generated the error:

```sql
SELECT *
from sys.dm_os_enumerate_filesystem('F:\technician','*');
```

> Msg 407, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
> internal error. The string routine in file sql\ntdbms\storeng\dfs\alloc\storagedmv.cpp, line 799 failed with HRESULT 0x8007007a.

The directory is 460 GB. I have also checked all permission and SQL Server service has all permission on the above directory.
As you can see the SqlServer is running with the last CU31.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: As an undocumented object, are you sure you want to use it? What are you actually trying to achieve here? Perhaps you would be better off doing the task *outside* of SQL Server.

Comment: I'm using Sqlserver to submit different query on filesystem and publish the results on SSRS (ReportingServer). This query do soem calculation file dimension, directory dimension, researche of duplicate files, etc etc

Comment: That doesn't tell me what you're actually trying to do though. Why use an undocumented object if you don't know what it actually does?

Comment: `0x8007007a` is `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` packaged as an `HRESULT`. There are many calls `dm_os_enumerate_filesystem` might be using that return this error, but the bottom line is that it's undocumented for a reason -- it serves Microsoft's internal purposes and is not intended to work for all possible scenarios. The workaround is to not use it, as MS engineers are highly unlikely to be motivated to modify this code to make it work for your specific use case (which would probably involve documenting it and officially supporting it).

Comment: I see, in anyway thanks for your help.
I can consider abandoning the dm_os_enumerate_filesystem (undocumented, only used for internal Microsoft reasons) and parallely using powershell (or C# code or a software like TreeSize) to query the filesystem to create csv files and upload them via SSIS in special tables .